# Upload file using spark framework on Tomcat server

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, java-8, spark-java

I want to know how to upload a file in Java 8 using Spark framework 2.6.0 on Tomcat server version 8.5.9. I found an example but only applies to the standard configuration of Spark (embedded jetty). http://sparkjava.com/documentation#examples-and-faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using Apache Commons Fileupload:

```
    File archivo = new File("MyPath");    
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setRepository(archivo);
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request.raw());
    FileItem item = items.stream()
                  .filter(e -> "file".equals(e.getFieldName()))
                .findFirst().get();
      String fileName = item.getName();
    item.write(new File(archivo, fileName));
```